# Refresh or Redraw picturebox in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I'm trying to view youtube captcha in my vb application but I don't know how to refresh/redraw the picture box. The youtube captcha is in http://www.youtube.com/cimg and the captcha is changing everytime I refresh the page. How can I do that using button or timer in vb.net to change the captcha. Here is the code I used to load the captcha to picturebox.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
        captchaBox.ImageLocation = "http://www.youtube.com/cimg" 
    End Sub
```

i try to use captchaBox.Refresh() but it's not working. I hope someone can help me. thx

Answer (score 0):

Refresh just redraws the control, it doesn't retrieve the image again. You need to reset the ImageLocation property for it to work. For example with a timer:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    captchaBox.ImageLocation = "http://www.youtube.com/cimg"
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    captchaBox.ImageLocation = "http://www.youtube.com/cimg"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
    PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://www.youtube.com/cimg"
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
    PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://www.youtube.com/cimg"
End Sub
```